# Use variadic function as template argument

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I'd like to make the following code work without changing the `Child1` and `Child2` classes at all:

```
#include <iostream>

int triple(int a) {
    return a * 3;
}

int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

template<int (*F)(int)>
class Parent {
    public:
        Parent(int a) {
            std::cout << "constructed: " << F(a) << std::endl;
        }
};

class Child1 : Parent<triple> {
    public:
        Child1(int a) : Parent(a) {}
};

/*class Child2 : Parent<add> {
    public:
        Child2(int a, int b) : Parent(a, b) {}
};*/

int main() {
    Child1 child(4);
    //Child2 child(5, 6);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see for example, `Child1` inherits from a `Parent` that has been instantiated with the `triple` function. Thus, when `Child1` is instantiated with a four, it outputs "`constructed: 12`".

In contrast, `Child2` is commented out, as it obviously does not work yet. In the main function, I am trying to pass two arguments to the `Child2` constructor, just like the underlying `add()` function expects it. Yet, `Parent`'s constructor only accepts a single argument and will probably need `template<typename Args...>` in front of it for the solution. Additionally, the `Parent` class will need a template argument like `int (*F)(Args...)`. Eventually, constructing a `Child2` instance like the main function does shall output "`constructed: 11`".

How can I accomplish this, i.e. create a template argument which is a function that can have any number of parameters? Again, please note that `Parent` class's code is the only thing that may be changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With C++17 You can use deduced non-type template parameter and make constructor a variadic template:

```
template<auto x_pointer_to_function>
class Parent
{
    public:
    template<typename... x_Args>
    Parent(x_Args &&... args)
    {
        std::cout << "constructed: " << ((*x_pointer_to_function)(::std::forward<x_Args>(args)...)) << std::endl;
    }
};
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rbWMxp5mqCPxClpp)

Comment: That's a lot of [redundant](https://wandbox.org/permlink/k0pLrVKbqfzqoKDx) `((*` you've got there.

Comment: Such defined, unconstrained constructor wins with the copy constructor

Comment: :p You can always use Facebook's fatal's `is_safe_overload` to prevent the copy constructor from getting invoked.... But that's a lot of boilerplate for such simple code:
https://github.com/facebook/fatal/blob/master/fatal/type/impl/safe_overload.h

Comment: Another example why I love C++17. Perfect answer!

Comment: @sigalor If you do use this in production code, you really, really, should use the `is_safe_overload` code I linked, to prevent accidentally invoking the copy constructor.

Comment: @Alexander Huszagh Thanks for the suggestion. Still, could you tell me why `= delete` does not work here and what's bad about the copy constructor exactly?

Comment: @sigalor Potential problem is that `Parent<&add> p1{1, 2}; Parent<&add> p2{p1};` will try to invoke this constructor instead of copy constructor and fail. Though this should not be much of an issue since it looks like `Parent` is not supposed to be used on its own and `Child` copy will still work as expected.

Comment: @sigalor Return value (and other stuff) can be constrained with `::std::is_invocable`

Comment: @sigalor Basically, variadic templates are considered perfect matches during overload resolution, and if you define a delete for the copy constructor or your own copy constructor, you will get an ambiguous overload issue since the compiler finds 2 perfect matches. This overload prevents the variadic constructor from matching any constructor with 1 argument taking the class itself.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh the call is not ambiguous. this constructor wins, because not const qualification is required for non const lvalue expression that is being copied. otherwise non-template functions take precedence

Comment: Oh whoops, I've had ambiguous conversions before, maybe an outdated compiler. Just checked with the latest GCC and you're right.

Answer (score 4):

It's too late to play?

I propose a variation of the `auto` based C++17 VTT's answer that use class specialization to extract the `Args...` input types (and the `Ret` type, if useful).

I mean

```
template <auto>
class Parent;

template <typename Ret, typename ... Args, Ret(*F)(Args...)>
class Parent<F>
 {
   public:
      Parent (Args const & ... as)
       { std::cout << "constructed: " << F(as...) << std::endl; }
 };
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <iostream>

int triple (int a)
 { return a * 3; }

long add (int a, int b)
 { return a + b; }

template <auto>
class Parent;

template <typename Ret, typename ... Args, Ret(*F)(Args...)>
class Parent<F>
 {
   public:
      Parent (Args const & ... as)
       { std::cout << "constructed: " << F(as...) << std::endl; }
 };

class Child1 : public Parent<triple>
 {
    public:
        Child1 (int a) : Parent{a}
         { }
 };

class Child2 : public Parent<add>
 {
    public:
        Child2 (int a, int b) : Parent{a, b}
         { }
 };

int main()
 {
   Child1 c1{4};
   Child2 c2{5, 6};
 }
```

Loose perfect forwarding but gain control over the number (and the types) of arguments.

Comment: Damn, this looks great as well, especially because of the custom (and possibly constrainable) return value (using enable_if)! Regarding the copy constructor discussion on the other answer, can you tell me if yours behaves any differently and/or what may be problematic about the copying?

Comment: @sigalor - yes, I suppose you can SFINAE impose something about the return type; regarding the copy constructor discussion... well... I don't understand it; I mean... if you want execute the template function `F` inside the constructor passing to it the argument of the constructor, you need a `std::tuple<Args...>` as member to pass arguments of first object to the second object.

Comment: Alright, I see :) Yet, please excuse that I'll keep the accepted answer as is, because it's the most minimalistic solution in the context of my question.

Comment: @sigalor - no problem at all: the VTT's answer is a good one (and I've upvoted it).